# Single Document Interface for Qt Creator on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

On Qt Creator, is there a way separate projects can be made to open in separate windows?

The visual separation of the source code files would make comparison / copying much easier.

EDIT: From sjwarner's answer it seems it's possible to open projects in separate windows under Linux and Windows. However, I am using Mac OS X

Comment: Did you try right-clicking on your .pro file and open with qt-creator?

Comment: @spyke Right click & open does not work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `open`'s man page,

```
-n  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.
```

I figured we can use it like this

```
open -n /path/to/Qt\ Creator.app
```

to open and work on multiple Qt Creator projects in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

> The visual separation of the source code files would make comparison /
>   copying much easier.

If you can't open multiple windows, you split the code window to show multiple documents side-by-side (the option is in the `Window` menu).  How effective this is for you depends on your screen size/resolution of course.

Comment: This is what I am doing currently but it is painful because there are files of the same name in both projects and it makes it confusing at times to figure which project a particular source file belongs to.

Comment: I can't see having multiple windows helping then, as Qt Creator only displays the filename in the titlebar/document viewer.  The only difference would be the project tree.

Comment: Keeping similarly named files from different projects in separate windows would be less confusing than keeping them side by side in split view at least to me - because often the files gets swapped with another one while debugging and bringing it back in its split-view requires the project tree which can be pretty long. Not convenient at all IMO

Answer (score 1):

I just open Qt Creator twice and then go from there...! You might find it easier to manage multiple projects using the session system though (*File->Session Manager*)...

Comment: How do you open two instances? When I am double clicking the Qt Creator application, it just brings the already opened instance to focus. Can't find any setting under Preferences to change the behavior either. I am on a Mac.

Comment: Ah, can't help you there I'm afraid - I can open multiple instances of Qt Creator on both Win and Linux but I don't use mac - sorry! I'd recommend adding that info to the question :)